# Syntax error with if column on exist with primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add a column which's also a primary key if it doesn't already exist on the table. If I do a simple

```
ALTER TABLE webinars_identities ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS id uuid
```

It will work but if I do

```
ALTER TABLE webinars_identities ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

It says it skips the alter table, but for some reason crashes right after:

```
NOTICE:  column "id" of relation "webinars_identities" already exists, skipping
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "webinars_identities" are not allowed
```

My original working query was

```
ALTER TABLE webinars_identities id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

But this is not repeatable without error.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The error speaks for itself. The column already exists. What is the table create statement , or are you running after the first alter table ?

Comment: That's exactly my point. I want to be able to run this query multiple times without crash, and if only the column doesn't exist, add it as primary key

Comment: `multiple primary keys for table "webinars_identities" are not allowed` is exactly what the issue is.

Comment: There could be multiple unique keys in a table, but only one primary key.

Comment: Ok i'll repeat it one more time. I thought the `IF NOT EXISTS` was here to prevent execution of the whole query, because it prevents the creation of the column, but it does not work, how do you avoid adding the column, and setting it as primary key, and everything that follows with a condition ? You're all repeating the error like I know what to do, I don't. I just want this query to be runable multiple times even if it exists. In other words: run the SQL query and either add the column or do nothing at all because it's already present.

Comment: Why are you running an `ALTER` statement on columns with constraint rules like primary keys *multiple times*? Relational database tables should have entire schema and constraint rules planned and designed **once** in advance and not adjusted on the fly *many* times afterwards. This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please provide the fuller background of your problem and not your attempted solution.

Comment: It should, but it's about migrations containing this query which could be run after this field has been added in the project i'm currently on, it's not supposed to happen all the time but i find it very difficult to just make a constraint out of it

Comment: I think it is an excellent idea to abort the running script if it duplicates a prior *migration*.

Comment: > Why are you running an ALTER statement on columns with constraint rules like primary keys multiple times?

Because people need to implement dynamic schemas and schema migrations in an idempotent way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it using `duplicate_column` exception and issue a notice, because someone rightly said that *errors should never pass silently.*

```
DO $body$ 
 BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE atable ADD COLUMN  id int primary key; --DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN duplicate_column THEN

  RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: %,%',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;

END $body$;
```

This will work the first time and does not fail on all following attempts, but gives you a message. All other errors if found in your statement will be raised as exceptions.

```
NOTICE:  ERROR: 42701,column "id" of relation "atable" already exists
DO
```

Comment: "Exception" means that the query will be aborted anyway in the end. All your "handling" is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DO $$ BEGIN TABLE atable ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS id int primary key ; exception when others then null ; END$$;
```

Comment: This will not throw exception for any run time error in the statement and will silence the genuine errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in postgres https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13277.1566920001%40sss.pgh.pa.us
Will be fixed in v13.0, hopefully.